# What is the supported version of istio to AKS 1.19.11

Tags: kubernetes, istio, azure-aks

Would like to know  what version of istio need to be required for AKS 1.19.11.

We will be going for AKS upgrade from 1.18.14 to 1.19.11.

Since istio version is 1.7.3 which version should go for istio to compatible with 1.19.11??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The note section at the top of the [Install Istio in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/servicemesh-istio-install?pivots=client-operating-system-linux) page provides a link to the [Istio General FAQ](https://istio.io/latest/about/faq/#what-deployment-environment), where the Istio team documents the supported Kubernetes versions for each Istio release:

> Istio is designed to be platform-independent, initially focused on
> Kubernetes. For our 1.10 release, Istio supports environments running
> Kubernetes (1.18, 1.19, 1.20, 1.21).

You can also track the [Support status of Istio releases](https://istio.io/latest/docs/releases/supported-releases/#support-status-of-istio-releases).

Comment: As per the document, we cant skip any minor versions.is it that way? since my current version is 1.7. i can go for 1.8 only.. cant go for 1.10 which is latest

Answer (score 0):

According to https://istio.io/latest/docs/releases/supported-releases/

Istio versions 1.8, 1.9, 1.10 all support Kubernetes 1.19

Comment: is there any dependecy like which should be upgraded first, like AKS or Istio..

Comment: Well if being strict, you should probably upgrade Istio first, since 1.8.-1.10 also support Kubernetes 1.18... but it might also work the other way